# How is this ShortHand notation (-=) executed?

Tags: java

```
        if(( amt%5 == 0 ) && ( bal > amt + 0.5 )) 
          {
            **bal -= amt - 0.5;**
            System.out.println("Updated Balance = " + bal);
           }
```

how is the statement(shorthand notation) in bold gets executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your expression:

> bal -= amt - 0.5;

This is shorthand notation for:

> bal = bal - (amt - 0.5);

Calculation is done as follows:

1. amt - 0.5 is calculated
2. bal - (result of 1.) is calculated
3. Result of 2. is assigned to bal

Lets assume `bal` is 10 initially and `amt` is 5 initially. Then calculation starts off with (5 - 0.5) = 4.5. Next, 10 - 4.5 = 5.5 is calculated. Finally, 5.5 is assigned to `bal`.

Answer (score 4):

```
bal -= amt - 0.5;
```

is shorthand notation for

```
bal = bal - (amt-0.5);
```

after that stement execution, `bal` gets update as `bal -(amt-0.5)`

Comment: which part of statement gets executed first in ** bal = bal - (amt-0.5); **

Comment: @BhaumikMehta Parenthesis have highest precedence. So `(amt-0.5)`

Comment: @BhaumikMehta what do you mean by *which part of statement gets executed first*?

Comment: Like the paranthesis part?

Comment: @BhaumikMehta Yes. It is.